# local-name usage with concat-function

Tags: xslt

Consider the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <node1></node1>
    <attribute1>test</attribute1>
</root>
```

and this transformation:

```
<xsl:template match="/root">
    <result>
        <xsl:for-each select="*[starts-with(local-name(), 'node')]">
            ---
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('attribute', string(position()))"/>
            ---
            <xsl:variable name="attribute" select="../*[local-name() = 'attribute1']"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$attribute"/>
            ---
            <xsl:variable name="test"
                select="../*[local-name() = concat('attribute', string(position()))]"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$test"/>
            ---
            <xsl:variable name="test2"
                select="../*[local-name() = concat('attribut','e1')]"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$test2"/>
            ---
        </xsl:for-each>
    </result>
</xsl:template>
```

Surprisingly for me, my variables `$test` is empty. I assume it has to do with using the `concat` or `string` function, but I can not figure out what causes this.

Any ideas? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the position of the `attribute1` node in the nodeset `../*` is 2 and `position()` refers to that. So the following line works

```
<xsl:variable name="test" select="../*[local-name() = concat('attribute', string(position()-1))]"/>
<xsl:value-of select="$test"/>
```

and gives the desired output.

Answer (score 2):

Note how different the result of your test will be, if you change the input to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <attribute1>test</attribute1>
    <node1></node1>
</root>
```

Why is that? Because the `position()` function, when placed inside a *predicate*, returns the position of the node being filtered (`../*` in your example), not the position of the *current* node. See a more detailed explanation here: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#predicates